# How to get BeautifulSoup to parse encoded characters such as "\u003C"?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have an html string where some of characters are encoded:

```
\u003C\/style\u003E\u003Cdiv\u003E\u003Cdiv style=\"position:relative;background: ......
```

I want to be able to parse it with BeautifulSoup. Is there an easy way to convert all these encoded characters into a format which BeautifulSoup support and then feed a result string to it?

Comment: it is chars in UTF-8. maybe you have to only `decode()` it.

Comment: @furas, how?......

Comment: Show more information:  how do you get this string, how do you display it on screen (maybe it only console problem, not HTML), is it string or bytes.

Comment: BTW: have you try to parse this with BS ? Did you get error message ? Show it in question. Create minimal working example with your problem so we could run it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to do that. Beautifulsoup can handle it correctly.
I ran the html string, it works.

[html string test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUjZ2.png)